# How do I load a delimited CSV file into Python?

Tags: python

1. I was able to get the file loaded in as a list like what is shown below.

[ABC, 1;2;3]
[DEF, 4;5;6]

2. However, I need it formatted like what is shown below.

   [ABC, 1]
       [ABC, 2]
       [ABC, 3]
       [DEF, 4]
   etc.

Here's the code that I used to load the file:

```
import csv

f = open('Sample.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print(row)
```

here's the output:

```
['Description', 'Article #']
['Build a Better Breakfast: Buy 2 save $2 on fruit/nuts/Milk - Kids M / Raisin Bran, RK M , Mini Wheat M PLUS Pop Tarts 12 ct.', '62758;65926;855924;856013;856179;553818;28107;29601;65928;51415;745406;414680;872002;29599;25717;25719;29608;62773;700401;746727;746743;746701;705400;817833']
['Community Coffee 12oz Ground Roast Coffee', '1027151;1027153;1059063;1170982;1170983;1170984;1170986;1170987;1170988;1170989;1182424;1216634;1216667;1225228;1228111;1245664;1245666;1248330;1249099;1249100;1308483;1330732;1330744;1336906']
["Keurig Green Mountain Core 12CT - Flavors Include:  Columbian, Breakfast Blend, Hazelnut, Dark Magic Extra Bold, Newman's Own Blnd, French Vanilla, Caribou Blnd, Nantucket, Caramel Vanilla Crm, Dark Magic Decaf, Half Caff, Tully's French Rst, Tully's Hawaiin Bln - Dc'd, Breakfast Decaf, Pumpkin Spice, Cinnamon Roll Cinnabon, Donut Shop Decaf, Donust Shop, French Vanilla Decaf,  Krispy Cream 9 New), Coconut Mocha (New), Donut Shop Dark (New)", '15136;15137;15166;15167;15168;22392;22664;22784;31015;31017;31020;40948;40980;41238;48742;48754;48756;48777;99555;08300;99555;08588;99555;086577']
['Starbucks K-Cups 10ct & 12oz R&G Coffee', '50794;50796;26470;26475;26479;30067;30082;41007;41008;41022;41196;50795;49424;49421;7700;30070;49414;49416;149195;149237;161588;373787;373886;373902;374264;374298;431858']
```

Comment: You will need to show your code here and example data. It looks like you have a mixture of delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for showing some code. I don't think the issue is with the delimiter (you can specify the delimiter in `csv.reader` but it is defaulting to comma). What you want is custom code IIUC. You will have to do a second split. Give me a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your initial question, I think this is the output you are looking for (although, the category starting "Keurig Green Mountain..." leaves me unsure). The CSV reader is correctly separating on the `,` delimiter, but you need a nested `for` loop to keep `ABC` persistent against a secondary split of the article number based on the `;` delimiter.

```
csv_reader_output = [['Description', 'Article #'],
['Build a Better Breakfast: Buy 2 save $2 on fruit/nuts/Milk - Kids M / Raisin Bran, RK M , Mini Wheat M PLUS Pop Tarts 12 ct.', '62758;65926;855924;856013;856179;553818;28107;29601;65928;51415;745406;414680;872002;29599;25717;25719;29608;62773;700401;746727;746743;746701;705400;817833'],
['Community Coffee 12oz Ground Roast Coffee', '1027151;1027153;1059063;1170982;1170983;1170984;1170986;1170987;1170988;1170989;1182424;1216634;1216667;1225228;1228111;1245664;1245666;1248330;1249099;1249100;1308483;1330732;1330744;1336906'],
["Keurig Green Mountain Core 12CT - Flavors Include:  Columbian, Breakfast Blend, Hazelnut, Dark Magic Extra Bold, Newman's Own Blnd, French Vanilla, Caribou Blnd, Nantucket, Caramel Vanilla Crm, Dark Magic Decaf, Half Caff, Tully's French Rst, Tully's Hawaiin Bln - Dc'd, Breakfast Decaf, Pumpkin Spice, Cinnamon Roll Cinnabon, Donut Shop Decaf, Donust Shop, French Vanilla Decaf,  Krispy Cream 9 New), Coconut Mocha (New), Donut Shop Dark (New)", '15136;15137;15166;15167;15168;22392;22664;22784;31015;31017;31020;40948;40980;41238;48742;48754;48756;48777;99555;08300;99555;08588;99555;086577'],
['Starbucks K-Cups 10ct & 12oz R&G Coffee', '50794;50796;26470;26475;26479;30067;30082;41007;41008;41022;41196;50795;49424;49421;7700;30070;49414;49416;149195;149237;161588;373787;373886;373902;374264;374298;431858']]

new_list = []

for row in csv_reader_output[1:]: # Avoid the title row
    description = row[0] # Your ABC
    for article in row[1].split(';'): # Splitting the article number
        new_list.append([description, article])

for item in new_list:
    print(item)
```